# I just cant find IK (Inverse Kinematics tab in toolbar)

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I just cant locate the IK (Inverse Kinematics) in bone constraint tab?

[image: This image show my problem]

Comment: I'm not noticing a "usual suspect" issue in your screenshot but try verifying that your lower leg bone has "Deform" checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*IK Constraint* is a *Bone Constraint*, not an *Object Constraint*, you need to switch to *Pose* mode (you are already) and click on the ***Bone Constraint*** tab.

Comment: He is in pose mode

Comment: he still needs to click on the Bone Constraint and not the Object Constraint tab  ;)

Comment: Yep, the Bone Constraint tab is the blue bone and he's not in it. That I did not see.

Comment: I just precised that the Pose mode was necessary because it's one of the conditions, you can't give a Bone Constraint in Object or Edit mode

Comment: I remember when I was still figuring out where everything is :P

Comment: yes; Blender can drive you mad sometimes ah ah   ;)

Comment: I am in pose mode I just cannot see the IK constraint in the bone constraints, while the IK is visible in render view

Comment: @Phil, hello, hard to say, maybe create a new question and share your file or at least show some screeenshots